# Is it possible to scan IBM BPM code with sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube-scan

I need to scan IBM BPM code with sonarqube. But no clue whether sonarqube supports or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible, for one thing. Sonarqube needs the code to be in a SCM in order to work. IBM BPM's code is saved in it's own proprietary repository. So yes, it's JS and theorically could be scanned by sonarqube, but the fact it's not accessible from outside the IDE makes it not scannable by sonarqube.